# How to remove "id" from json string in ruby on rails?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, json

I have got data without "id" field from database. But when I parse the data to json string and show it on screen,  I saw an "id" field on json string. How to remove this "id" field?

Here is my code:

-report_logic.rb

```
def fetch_data ()
@datalist=WorkEarlyOverTime
@datalist = @datalist.joins("INNER JOIN `works` ON `work_early_over_times`.`work_id` = `works`.`id`")
  @datalist = @datalist.select('`work_early_over_times`.work_id AS 1次協力会社名','`work_early_over_times`.working_temp_person AS 職種名','`work_early_over_times`.working_temp_hour AS 作業場所','`work_early_over_times`.at_time_overtime_start AS 作業内容','`works`.`contents`')
@datalist = @datalist.where(work_id: $work_id)
return @datalist
end
```

- report_controller.rb

```
def work_late
report_logic = ReportLogic.new(params)
@work_late = report_logic.fetch_data()
render action: :work_late
end
```

- work_late.json.jbuilder

```
json.一覧 @work_late
```

When I show the string I expected the output is:

```
{"一覧":[
    {"1次協力会社名":1,
    "職種名":"0",
    "作業場所":"0.00 ",
    "作業内容":"2000-01-01T19:00:00.000+00:00",
    "contents":"作業内容1"}
    ]}
```

but the actual output is:

```
{"一覧":[
    {"id":null,
    "1次協力会社名":1,
    "職種名":"0",
    "作業場所":"0.00 ",
    "作業内容":"2000-01-01T19:00:00.000+00:00",
    "contents":"作業内容1"}
    ]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your desired output is a `JSON`, you could try `.as_json` by excepting the id field as follows:

```
@datalist.select('`work_early_over_times`.work_id AS 1次協力会社名','`work_early_over_times`.working_temp_person AS 職種名','`work_early_over_times`.working_temp_hour AS 作業場所','`work_early_over_times`.at_time_overtime_start AS 作業内容','`works`.`contents`').as_json(:except => :id)
```

Your detailed fetch_data function will be like this:

```
def fetch_data ()
    @datalist=WorkEarlyOverTime
    @datalist = @datalist.joins("INNER JOIN `works` ON `work_early_over_times`.`work_id` = `works`.`id`")
      @datalist = @datalist.select('`work_early_over_times`.work_id AS 1次協力会社名','`work_early_over_times`.working_temp_person AS 職種名','`work_early_over_times`.working_temp_hour AS 作業場所','`work_early_over_times`.at_time_overtime_start AS 作業内容','`works`.`contents`').as_json(:except => :id)
    @datalist = @datalist.where(work_id: $work_id)
    return @datalist
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If `id` is always `null` then just ignore all nils:

```
json.ignore_nil!
json.一覧 @work_late
```

If that's not the case then you have to filter out the `id` before serializing it. One way would be:

```
json.一覧 @work_late.serializable_hash.except("id")
```